# php get mysql result not as array, but as text

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get text result like:

```
+----+-------+----------------------------------+----+
| id | login | pwd                              | su |
+----+-------+----------------------------------+----+
|  1 | root  | c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b |  1 |
+----+-------+----------------------------------+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

in PHP (string).

Example in php:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
for (; $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); $data[] = $row);
```

I get array of arrays ($data):

```
$data = 
   0 => (id=>1, login=>root..)
```

But i want to get this as **string**:

```
+----+-------+----------------------------------+----+
| id | login | pwd                              | su |
+----+-------+----------------------------------+----+
|  1 | root  | c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b |  1 |
+----+-------+----------------------------------+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

By the way for query "insert into users set login = 'sp', pwd = 1, su = 0", this string must be "Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.18 sec)".

Like sql terminal though php!

Comment: That's nice but you're going to have to provide more info. What's your schema? What have you tried? Are you getting any errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the table itself, together with all the plusses, dashes and bars that mysql client draws?

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation processor](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Hint: loop over the keys to produce the header, then loop the values for the rows. You'll need to first find the longest value of each column so that you can pad each cell with the required amount of spaces in order for everything to line up.

Comment: use $data[] = $row as $data=$row then you will get as array of records,, and try to implode ,,, you will get things done

Comment: mysql_query just like for illustrative purpose. Its not the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either invoke `mysql` client as an external command, or build the ASCII drawing table yourself. You can't get it purely by using PHP's MySQL library functions. Off the top of my head,

```
$result = `echo 'SELECT * FROM users' | mysql --user=username --password=password dbname`;
```

(ugly, slow, insecure, don't recommend); or simply get it as the array, iterate, and decorate with plusses imitating what `mysql` does (recommended). It's really easy.

However, I have no clue why you'd want that, unless you're using your PHP program as a command-line tool.

Comment: Yeah, i want sql terminal by php.

Answer (score 0):

Collect the database result into an array of arrays(your $data variable is correct)

```
echo ascii_table($data);
```

I stole the following from someone named stereofrog

```
function ascii_table($data) {

    $keys = array_keys(end($data));

    # calculate optimal width
    $wid = array_map('strlen', $keys);
    foreach($data as $row) {
        foreach(array_values($row) as $k => $v)
            $wid[$k] = max($wid[$k], strlen($v));
    }

    # build format and separator strings
    foreach($wid as $k => $v) {
        $fmt[$k] = "%-{$v}s";
        $sep[$k] = str_repeat('-', $v);
    }
    $fmt = '| ' . implode(' | ', $fmt) . ' |';
    $sep = '+-' . implode('-+-', $sep) . '-+';

    # create header
    $buf = array($sep, vsprintf($fmt, $keys), $sep);

    # print data
    foreach($data as $row) {
        $buf[] = vsprintf($fmt, $row);
        $buf[] = $sep;
    }

    # finis
    return implode("\n", $buf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can please query the following sql:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id, ' | ', login, ' | ', pwd, ' | ', su)
```

`AS 'User Object' FROM users group by id`

Result Would Be:

[image]